# Why does the React Router history length increase on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The first time I open the app, the length of the history object (returned by the [useHistory](https://usehooks.com/useHistory/) Hook) is 3.

On every further refresh, the length gets incremented. Why is that? Does this happen in production too?

Environment:

- create-react-app@3.2.0
- react-router@5.1.2
- react-router-dom@5.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to the site in a tab where you have been visiting other pages, history.length will be >1. history.length is the number of locations in the joint session history, not the current site's session history.

Even opening a new tab and entering the url of your app will mean a history.length of 2: blank tab + your url. You can get a length of 1 if you arrive directly at the page through a link on a new window/tab.

This may explain >1 length when first opening your app. This doesn't answer why your app increases the length on refresh, so it may have to do with your specific structure.

Answer (score 1):

> - react-router@5.1.2
> - react-router-dom@5.1.2

I think you don't need to use **`react-router-dom`** and **`react-router`** together.

Use only **react-router-dom**, as **`react-router-dom`** & **`react-router-native`** uses **`react-router`** at core

Comment: Not an answer to my question per se, but thanks for this! I removed the dependency on `react-router` and the app still loads correctly.