# Is it fine to push to React Router history indefinitely?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Say we have Home, Page A, Page B and Page C. If I do this:

1. Open Page B
2. Go Home
3. Go to Page B

This pushes at least 3 routes in the history object. If I repeat the steps, there will be 6 items. This is true when pushing directly via `history.push` and also when using the Link component's with the `to` prop.

The only way to keep complexity under control is by checking the previous location and then doing either `history.goBack` or `history.push`: [Check history previous location before goBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409586/check-history-previous-location-before-goback-react-router-v4).

The catch is that managing the `history` object can become a very complicated task very quickly. Just by adding a navigation bar that is rendered on every page in the app, you add at least "n-1" places from where you can go back home (assuming home is one of the navigation tabs).

Should we be concerned about this and handle the previous location?

---

Possibly related question: [Why does the React Router history length increase on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892073/why-does-the-react-router-history-length-increase-on-refresh)

Environment:

- history is BrowserHistory
- react-router@5.1.2
- react-router-dom@5.1.2

Comment: Seems very much of a muchness to me, I'm not entirely sure of what the question is.

Comment: I updated the post and rephrased the question at the end

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The `history` object is meant to hold the list of pages the user previously visited. If the user visited the same page more than once why shouldn't that page appear in the list more than once?

Comment: @ElanHamburger Hmm okay, for some reason I thought that it's supposed to hold the minimum number of pages in there. That is, if I have an app with 4 pages, there should always be maximum 4 items in history, and use `history.goBack` to navigate backward.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I believe `history` is supposed to mimic browser history. If you go to page A, click a link to page B, click a link to page A, and click the back button twice, you should end up at page A again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Elan Hamburger's comments, I now understand that the `BrowserHistory` is meant to behave like this. Normally, in the browser, if you go to page A, then to page B, then back to page A, clicking back 3 times will return you to the home page.

So you shouldn't really mind the size of the `history` object, at least certainly not if you don't have billions of users.